# Unnecessary condition in the definition of an isomorphism of root systems

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, root-systems

Let $R$ be a root system in a vector space $V$ (of characteristic $0$) with coroots $R^{\vee} \subseteq V^*$.
Recall that for every $\alpha \in R$ the corresponding coroot $\alpha^{\vee} \in R^{\vee}$ is uniquely determined by $R$ via the conditions $\alpha^{\vee}(\alpha) = 2$ and $\beta - \alpha^{\vee}(\beta) \alpha \in R$ for every $\beta \in R$.

From what I’ve seen an *isomorphism of root systems* $f \colon (V, R) \to (V', R')$ is usually defined as a vector space isomorphism $V \to V'$ such that $f(R) = R'$ and
$$
  f(\alpha)^{\vee}( f(\beta) )
  =
  \alpha^{\vee}(\beta)
  \quad
  \text{for all $\alpha, \beta \in R$} \,.
  \tag*{(1)}
$$
(This definition can for example be found in [Definition 18.13.1, 1] and in [p. 43, 2].)

> **Question:**
>   Why is condition $(1)$ explicitely required?

It seems to me that this condition automatically holds:

If $f \colon V \to V'$ is any isomorphism of vector spaces (not necessarily with $f(R) = R'$) then we can push forward the root system $R$ of $V$ to a root system $\tilde{R}'$ of $V'$ given by the set $\tilde{R}' = f(R)$ and coroots $f(\alpha)^{\vee} = \alpha^\vee \circ f^{-1}$.

If now $f(R) = R'$ then the root systems $R'$ and $\tilde{R}'$ have the same underlying set, so for $f(\alpha) \in f(R)$ we can consider its coroot with respect to both $R'$ and $\tilde{R}'$.
But it follows from the above uniqueness of coroots that these coincide.
Thus $f(\alpha)^{\vee}(f(\beta)) = \alpha^{\vee}(f^{-1}(f(\beta))) = \alpha^{\vee}(\beta)$ as required by $(1)$.

---

[1] *Lie Algebras and Algebraic Groups* by Tauvel, Yu
[2] *Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory* by James E. Humphreys

Comment: Why do you have $f(\alpha)^{\vee} = \alpha^\vee \circ f^{-1}$, if $f$ is just a vector space isomorphism with $f(R)=R'$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: The equation $f(\alpha)^{\vee} = \alpha^{\vee} \circ f^{-1}$ refers to the pushed forward root system $\tilde{R}'$, which is at this point of the argument independent of $R'$. I rewrote the question to make this (hopefully) more understandable.

Comment: It seems to me that this pushed forward root system  just gives $(1)$, so we do not need $(1)$ when using the "pushed forward root system". However, the proposition is not mentioning the "pushed forward root system", so it seems appropriate to require it in form of $(1)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I’m trying to argue that $f(R) = R'$ gives that $R'$ **is** the push forwarded root system. Thus the requirement $(1)$  is not needed for $R'$ as it is automatic for the push forwarded root system.

Comment: I vaguely remember thinking along similar lines years ago, and in section 3.1.4 in my thesis I claimed (in a slightly different setting though) that this often-stated condition is indeed redundant. Apparently back then I found one reference which agreed, namely, D. Winter: *Abstract Lie Algebras*, MIT Press 1972, sections 3.7.3.1.2/4 and 3.7.3.4.3. I do not have this reference at hand right now though, so double-check. (I understand though that most sources would state it explicitly even if it's redundant, it's just handy to have.)